# Update a wordpress rest api using javascript fetch method

Tags: fetch-api, wordpress-rest-api

This is the index.php of my plugin where I am registering a custom POST endpoint.

```
function __construct()
{
    add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'add_custom_api'));
}
function add_custom_api()
{
    register_rest_route('wyr/v1', 'putAns', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => array($this, 'putAns')
    ));
}
```

But, I want to insert the data inside this endpoint using a fetch post method from javascript.

```
function putAns($data)
{
    return (); // INSERT SOMETHING FROM JAVASCRIPT
}
```

This is the javascript code that I'm failing with:

```
async clickHandler(e) {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost/plugdev/wp-json/wyr/v1/putAns", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: 'A blog post by DAVID',
            body: 'Brilliant post on fetch API',
            userId: 1,
        })
    });
    var data1 = await response.json();
    console.log(data1)
}
```

There are a lot of other details missing but this is the general gist of the issue: Onclick of a button, I want to change the value of a a property inside this object. Then, I'll have to catch this request from php and insert it into the database.